# JSON Deserialize to an interface

Tags: .net, json, serialization, deserialization

I have a class used for communication "CommunicationClass1".
It has a property ProductName and a lot of other properties and classes.

After deserialize it I need to feed it to the constructor of the correct adapter class "AdaptorClass1" based on the property ProductName.

(The adapterClasses are inheriting from an AdaptorBase class)

It is a different software that is saving the CommunicationClass1 to a JSON file and I need to load it. A second softeare may use a different communication class "CommunicationClass2" and I need to load it with the same routine as well.

So question, how can I create a routine that deserializes any communication class and reads out the ProductName so I can then load (deserialize) the file with the correct communication class type and feed it to the correct adapter class?

Basically I don't know if the file was serialized as type CommunicationClass1 or CommunicationClass2 but I know it will have a property ProductName.

Is this doable if so how?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you definitely need some differentiation criteria after you de-serialize your payload. One possibility is to pick up one JSON from each source and compare them so you can identify a particular property that only exist at a given source. If you could do that, the you would simply take the decision based on that criteria. Hope it helps.

Comment: Okay so there is no way to just read in the JSON to a string and parse it such that I could get the value (string type) of the ProductName property.
I suppose I could just read it in as text and do this, but I hoped the Newton JSON routines could simplify it.

Comment: Please note that you dont need to "parse" the JSON by hand. You should make use of your's language of choice support to decode it. If  you can infer the type of object by just inspecting the 'ProductName' property, then that's the way to go.